# Multiple instances of transition property among classes used on a single element

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X2s6W/

CSS:

```
div{
    background: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: background 0.5s
}
div.one{
    background: red
}
div.two{
    height: 200px;
    transition: height 0.5s    
}
```

JS:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if($("div.one").length > 0){
        $("div").removeClass("one").addClass("two");
    }else{
        $("div.two").removeClass("two").addClass("one");
    }
}, 1000);
```

Problem:

When going from `one` to `two`, only the `height` transitions, but the background doesn't.
When going from `two` to `one`, only the `background` transitions. but the height doesn't.
The behavior is identical in Chrome, Firefox, and IE10.

Question: Is there a way to combine these classes, or must the CSS be changed to accommodate this limitation? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting both the transition in both the rules.

```
div.one{
     background: red;
     transition: height 0.5s, background 0.5s; 
}
div.two{
    background: green;
    height: 200px;
    transition: height 0.5s, background 0.5s; 
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yn3tF/)**